# Servlet Connection Pooling

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I get a connection from mysql database using Connection pool with servlet

Am getting these error:

HTTP Status 404 - /TomcatConnectionPooling/

type Status report

message /TomcatConnectionPooling/

description The requested resource (/TomcatConnectionPooling/) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/5.5.20

Comment: Your Servlet is not deployed at all. This is not a problem with your database or connection pool. Make sure your project compiles and is deployed in your tomcat server successfully. You might check the ``tomcat/logs/catalina.out`` file for that.

Comment: The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.

Comment: Tomcat 5.5 was released in '04. Is there any good reason you are using it well beyond the end-of-life date?